# Construction mode multiple points

Tags: qgis, digitizing

Is there a way to define multiple points to snap in the construction mode in advanced digitizing?

Let's suppose I want the value -26- from point 3 to 4 but also want a value -31- from point 1 to 4. How would I do that?

[image]

Comment: You could use `Geometry by expression` and define an expression to create a new geometry if that is an option for you?

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to begin creating an expression as such. Would you mind to explain to me or indicate some references?

Comment: The most simple version is something lieke that: `make_line (make_point(x,y), make_point(x,y) )`, where you should replace x and y by the coordinates of the points. You thus connect with a line the points you create. Add more points if needed.

Comment: You could also use `project` expression to create a point at a certain distance ang angle from another point. Also intersections etc. are possible using expressions.

Comment: Thus it depends what you actually need

Comment: oh I understand it now, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. Too much trouble considering I have more than 1000 parcels to draw. Thanks for the answer nevertheless.